# Swift protocol with associated type and shadow type erasure

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, associated-types

I need to pass an object which implements a protocol with associated type into a method, which accepts a protocol. This is not possible in Swift (up to the latest Swift 5) so I use type erasure with a shadow protocol based on [this blog](https://medium.com/dunnhumby-data-science-engineering/swift-associated-type-design-patterns-6c56c5b0a73a).

```
protocol ShadowA {
    func test(data: Any) -> String
}

extension ShadowA {
    func test(data: Any) -> String {
        return "shadow"
    }
}

protocol A: ShadowA {
    associatedtype AT

    func test(data: AT) -> String
}

class SpecificA: A {
    typealias AT = Int

    func test(data: Int) -> String {
        return "specific"
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I pass the object into the method then the "shadow's default implementation" is called instead of the "generic" one's. You can check the [playground](https://iswift.org/playground?8nt0eG&v=4) to see what is happening.

Is there something wrong or this use case is not possible in Swift at all?

Answer (score 1):

This dynamic Dispatch  and direct dispatch  Magic for more explain about that check this [swift-method-dispatch](https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/12/swift-method-dispatch/)

> Dynamic dispatch is the process of selecting which implementation of a
>   polymorphic operation (method or function) to call at run time.

Any method that implemented in `protocol extension` is  **Direct dispatched**

i will explain more

because `ShadowA` is `protocol` and have `default implementation` in extension so  compiler mind have this hint  "`Any class can adopt to this protocol without implement this method because it have default implementation`"

***Direct Dispatch***

So at this Line What compiler know about `test(data:Any)` from item  and because item  is protocol with default implementation so it direct it to call direct default implementation

```
return "in method: \(item.test(data: 0))"

func passedIntoMethod(item: ShadowA) -> String {
    return "in method: \(item.test(data: 0))"
}
```

Also At this line

```
let a2: ShadowA = SpecificA()   // becuse compiler know only about a2 at this line that it is Protocol so it direct dispatch it  
print(a2.test(data: 0))
```

***Dynamic Dispatch***

Here compiler know that a1 is concreate  type so it call test Method that implemented inside it . if not implemented then it will call default implementation

```
let a1 = SpecificA()
print(a1.test(data: 0))
```

Comment: Funny thing is that when I have a breakpoint inside a method, which accepts a shadow protocol, the program pauses, then when I call the method from debugger, the correct "generic" method is called on the object. Then step over the  code, which calls the same method as I called from the debugger, the "shadow methods" is called i.e. debugger calls the generic method but real code calls the shadow method.

Comment: Dispatch is at run time

Comment: So the debugger sees the object, inside the method, as a concrete type (instead of just as shadow protocol) so it can/will call the correct method?